# Angular - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm developing an angular project that consumes a Web API .NET Core project.
I have used JWT Bearer authorization in my web API project, and now I want to use it with angular as well.

I have enabled CORS in Startup.cs as below and used `[EnableCors("ApiCorsPolicy")]` attribute with my controllers

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//.....
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials();
            }));
//.....
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
//.....
            
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });            
//.....
}
```

Then for my angular project, I installed the angular2-jwt library and used it as described in this [article](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-2/)

But I received this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44346/api/items' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And yes when I checked the Network tab, I didn't find the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, but when I remove the `Authorize` attribute from my controller it works and I can see the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is added to the response headers successfully.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try moving `app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");` *above* `app.UseRouting();` in the `Configure` function.

Comment: `UseCors` should be before `UseAuthentication`/`UseAuthorization`, but after `UseRouting`. `UseHttpsRedirection` should be first on your list, too. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks a lot, it works now. This was a very silly error :)